# Google Script to watch multiple sheets: how do I simplify this script?

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I am new to Google Scripts, and trying to automate some process in Google Spreadsheets. I have found a way to move a row from one sheet to another based on the value in a specific column. But, to make it work across multiple sheets, I have duplicated the code for every sheet. I'm sure there must be a way to simplify this, but I'm getting stuck. See my code below.

```
function onEdit() {
 // moves a row from a sheet to another when a magic value is entered in a column
// adjust the following variables to fit your needs
// see https://productforums.google.com/d/topic/docs/ehoCZjFPBao/discussion

var sheetNameToWatch = "BRG";

var columnNumberToWatch = 3; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatch = "done";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Done";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}

var sheetNameToWatch = "Lesotho";

var columnNumberToWatch = 3; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatch = "done";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Done";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}


var sheetNameToWatch = "Bosman";

var columnNumberToWatch = 3; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatch = "done";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Done";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();


if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch && range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. It creates an array of all sheet names not equal to "Done" and then loops through your code to see if a sheet has been edited with "done" in column C.

```
function onEdit() {
var columnNumberToWatch = 3; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
var valueToWatch = "done";
var sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo = "Done";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getActiveCell();

var sheetNameToWatch=[] //Array of Sheet names
var names = ss.getSheets()
  for( j=0;j<names.length;j++) {
    var n= names[j].getSheetName();
      if(n!="Done"){ //If Sheet name not "Done" add to array
       sheetNameToWatch.push(n)
  }}
for(i=0;i<sheetNameToWatch.length;i++){
if (sheet.getName() == sheetNameToWatch[i] && range.getColumn() ==  columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNameToMoveTheRowTo);
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1, 1,      sheet.getLastColumn()).moveTo(targetRange);
sheet.deleteRow(range.getRow());
}}
}
```

Comment: This answer is excellent, because the script can now be applied to any spreadsheet. It works perfectly.